# Change in EC2 instance type not reflecting in Cloud9 environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I have an existing Cloud9 environment that is of EC2 instance environment type and has a t3.medium (4 GiB RAM + 2 vCPU) with EBS only storage volume.

Under EC2 management console, I went to the EC2 instance that is attached to the Cloud9 environment and stopped it. Then under Actions --> Instance Settings --> Change instance type --> changed the instance type to t3.large from existing t3.medium.

I clicked refresh till all the 2 status checks passed OK for the t3.large instance.

Once I went back to the Cloud9 environment and go to Details --> EC2 Instance tab, I still see the instance type as t3.medium, not t3.large.

**Troubleshoot**

Went to CloudFormation console --> Stacks --> Drifts. Clicked on "Detect Stack Drift" and then refresh. Showed the Drift Status as below

[image: Stack_Drift_Status]

Next, went to Cloud9 environment and saw the instance type changed from t3.medium to t3.large.

**Solution**

Drift status need to be detected after any resource change to be reflected in Cloud9 environment.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud9 spins up the instance using CloudFormation.  Apparently, Cloud9 also pulls the current configuration for its console from CloudFormation stack template.

There is a constraint in CloudFormation that any changes done on the resources directly can only be identified as a drift by CloudFormation, but CloudFormation will not update the stack template based on known drift.

I was able to reproduce your case, but I could not update the stack template after I manually changed the resource.  The stack uses the tags that are restricted for use by AWS services, which prevented me from updating the template.

The overall result is that the underlying EC2 will change, but the Cloud9 console will reflect only the original (stale) state of the configuration.

Comment: Went to CloudFormation console --> Stacks --> Drifts. Clicked on "Detect Stack Drift" and then refresh. Got the Drift Status added under Stack Policy. Now, under Cloud9 environment, the instance type changed from t3.medium to t3.large

Comment: Wait a sec!  What did you do to get "the Drift Status added under Stack Policy"?

Comment: Detected the Stack Drift from CloudFormation console which added the Drift entry under Stack Drift Status. Will have to wait a bit to get the drifts reflected. Next, in Cloud9 environment, refreshing will show you the changed instance type, which was initially not showing

Comment: Oh, OK.  I thought you somehow managed to change the stack policy.  The Cloud9 environment I spinned up just now in us-east-1 did not reflect the change after I detected the drift in Cfn, but maybe I simply did not wait long enough.

Comment: No I didn't change anything in CF stack policy